# How can error of type any be changed to error of type Error?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';

class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error:any) {  
    // do something with the exception
     console.log('Error',error);
  }
}
```

I am using the ErrorHandler in order to catch the exceptions that are generated.
The error caught is of type ERROR but here in class error is of type `error:any` due to which console.log('Error', error); prints `Error Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]` as the type of error object is any.

How can I change the error object to ERROR in `handleError(error:any)`?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't type-check in runtime. And as an `Error` IS `any` (`any` just means 'any object'), calling `handleError(error: any)` with an `Error` object is perfectly valid.

It's kind of like "opting out" of the type-checking during transpilation into javascript.

So when you say: "prints Error Uncaught (in promise): [object Object] as the type of error object is any.", chances are the "any" type IS infact an Error. When you print out an object to the console it always looks like `[object Object]` (unless your console has some nice parsing like Chrome's console, where it displays an interactive object). If you want the json: do `error.toJSON()` and you'll see all the fields in the error object and be able to tell whether it is actually an `Error`.

I suspect you want to do something along the lines of:

```
console.log('Error', error.message);
```

I don't know what fields Error has off the top of my head. If you don't either, you can use the `as` command to make things easy when you're writing code:

```
handleError(e: any) {  
  // do something with the exception
  const error as Error;
  console.log('Error', error.message);
}
```

Of course, that would break if anyone uses it on a non Error object (or an object that doesn't have a `message` so it's probably best to do a check:

```
handleError(e: any) {  
  // do something with the exception
  const error as Error;
  if (error.message) {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
  } else {
     console.log('Unspecified error!');
  }
}
```